# Amplify DataStore: how to update item not in local database

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, datastore

I am successfully using DataStore. However I am wondering how to do the following:

I have set the maxRecordsToSync to 1000 items. I can get an item directly from DynamoDb (that is not in the local database, lets say item number 10, 000) using the DynamoDBClient plus the QueryCommand and GetItemCommand.

My problem is how to update this item. I could probably do it using the DynamoDBClient and the PutItemCommand, however I have read somewhere that I should not do this as this would not update the version number and would therefore cause problems with syncing.

My question is therefore, what is the best practice to update an item retrieved directly from dynamoDb using the DynamoDBClient? I am asuming that I cannot use DataStore.save() as the item is not in the local database?
Thanks